# Copy list of files to specific paths with Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Scratching my head for a while now, but I would like to copy an arbitrary list of files with paths to under specified path in system.

File layout:

```
data/a/file1.ext1
data/b/randomfile.ext2
data/c/file3.ext3
data/c/subdir/randomfile.2
```

Running `make -f Makefile deploy DESTDIR=/path/to/somewhere` copies those files to:

```
$(DESTDIR)/a/file1.ext1
$(DESTDIR)/b/randomfile.ext2
$(DESTDIR)/c/file3.ext3
$(DESTDIR)/c/subdir/randomfile.2
```

`Makefile`:

```
$FILES = \
    a/file1.ext1 \
    b/randomfile.ext2 \
    c/file3.ext3 \
    c/subdir/randomfile.2

ifneq ($(filter env_check,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$())
  ifndef DESTDIR
    $(error DESTDIR not defined)
  endif
endif

# lots of currently broken rules :(
# check whether target directory has certain structure
# check whether all the files listed in $(FILES) are in repository
```

Comment: Which Unix? `cp -pr` does what you want. `pax` and `cpio` too, where available. I take it `man` is not enough.

Comment: @Mischa: Regular unix. I know about `cp -pr` but if I wanted to add some dependencies (like checking whether target paths or even all the files in `$(FILES)` exist), things fail due to invalid targets...

Comment: In those cases (`$(DESTDIR)` does not exist, or one of the files does not exist), what do you want to happen?

Comment: @Beta If file in $(DESTDIR) does not exist or differs it will be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
FILES := ...
DST_FILES := $(addprefix $(DESTDIR)/,$(FILES))

ifneq ($(filter env_check,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$())
  ifndef DESTDIR
    $(error DESTDIR not defined)
  endif
endif

all: $(DST_FILES)

$(DST_FILES) : ${DESTDIR}/% : %
    @echo "$< ==> $@"
    @[[ -e $< ]] || (echo "some error for $<" && false)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @cp  $< $@
```

**[Edit]**:
Although the version somewhat worked, I still needed to do following adjustments:

- Files in source repository are stored under `data` directory - fixed by using `$addprefix` call
- When file in `$(DESTDIR)` already existed, it was never copied - used the `.FORCE` target. (Another option would be `--always-make` commandline option).

Eventually, the working Makefile looks like that:

```
# File are stored under data/
FILES= \
    foo/file1.ext \
    bar/file2.txe \
    bar/dir/file3.txt

ifneq ($(filter env_check,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$())
  ifndef DESTDIR
    $(error DESTDIR not defined)
  endif
endif

.PHONY: deploy help

help:
    @echo "Deploy stuff"

# Check whether certain directories in the output are present
env_check:
    @test -d $(DESTDIR)/WEB-INF -a -d $(DESTDIR)/META-INF || \
        ( echo "DESTDIR: \"$(DESTDIR)\" is not proper deployment path" && exit 1 )

DST_FILES := $(addprefix $(DESTDIR)/, $(FILES))

# We need to add our path prefix to local files and FORCE to always do the copying
$(DST_FILES) : $(addprefix $(DESTDIR), %) : $(addprefix data,%) .FORCE
    @cp -pv $< $@

.FORCE:

deploy: env_check $(DST_FILES)
    @echo "Deployment done..."
```

Comment: Basically yes, although.. there's a small issue that's causing the problem - I have all my files under `data` in the repository.

Comment: Ok, managed to fix the `data` prefix issue by changing the rule to `$(DST_FILES) : $(addprefix $(DESTDIR), %) : $(addprefix data,%)`

Comment: Now there's an issue when file already exists under `$(DESTDIR)`, it won't be updated.. (am I using a wrong tool for the job?)

Comment: Ahh, sorry, missed the `data` directory part.    You shouldn't need `addprefix`, unless you're modifying a list (and `%` isn't a list in this case), so your rule could be `$(DST_FILES) : $(DESTDIR)/% : data/%`.   This is slightly more readable IMO.  Also you could add the line `DESTDIR:=$(DESTDIR:/=)` near the top to strip a trailing slash if the user specified one.  It's common practice to not include a trailing slash in a directory name variable.

Comment: As far as not copying / `.FORCE` goes, in the original, the file would not be copied if the one in the `$(DESTDIR)` directory was newer than the source version -- so theoretically, it would not copy files it's already copied (kind of the point of make).   If you want to assume that the files are always out of date, and always need to be copied, then yes, `.FORCE` would be the way to go.